# Is it appropriate to carry furniture with bike and suggestion for equipment

Tags: trailer

I am coming from a culture where there are not many bike roads. 
But now I am moving to a place where bike roads are awesome and cool.

Since I do not know the "bike culture" well in Denmark while I think [this should be acceptable](http://www.mrmoneymustache.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/radiant_heat.jpg)  I wanted to ask if I try something like below,

[image]

Is it legally or culturally bad . BTW While looking for stuff I am trying find ones close to my house which is far from center to avoid dense population and narrow bike roads.

If it is OK do you have any advise for a trailer type or other equipment(for example like green and orange ropes in the picture) to accomplish that?

Comment: The question being specific to Denmark makes it tricky - you're going to have to wait for someone who's been there for a while to get a solid answer.

Comment: Note that you can carry 6 kids in a suitable trailer in Denmark, but I don't think that change affects generic cargo: http://www.eltis.org/discover/news/denmark-allows-more-kids-cargo-bikes  But 6 kids is a fair bit of cargo, so maybe a couple of couches wouldn't be as obvious as you think :)

Comment: Take multiple trips.

Comment: Whomever reading this thread in Denmark I found a site for renting trailers finally it might help you maybe as well https://freetrailer.dk/book-en-trailer/

Comment: Heh bike looks tired, and is having a wee lie down, like a puppy who has walked far enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the [photos on the Christiana](http://www.christianiabikes.com/en/category-product/everything-else/) website I think you'll be fine. The exact law I'm not sure of, I can't find a translation of their bike laws online.

[image] [image]

It seems that people do carry big loads on bikes there, which isn't surprising given the strength of their cycling culture. You have the right idea about not doing it in rush hour.

The generic load carrying questions are easier to answer. I suggest not loading with the centre of gravity as high as your photo because it means you can't ride on roads where there's a side slope, and cornering is harder. But if that's the trailer you have, that's the trailer you'll use. Just be careful.

I would build or modify a trailer that's as wide as I can get down the paths in the area, once you have somewhere to live. I have [built trailers](http://moz.geek.nz/mozbike/ride/carry/index.html) more than a metre wide and not had problems, and in both cases I have built them so I can have a flat platform over the wheels, which lets me have loads wider than the trailer easily.

[image]([big](http://moz.geek.nz/mozbike/ride/carry/load-bikes-08-moz.jpg)) [image]([big](http://moz.geek.nz/mozbike/ride/carry/load-bikes-08-moz.jpg))

(same trailer, flipped upside down to use a second set of dropouts. Or just [load it so you can have a higher layer of stuff that sticks out more](http://moz.geek.nz/mozbike/ride/carry/load-bikes-04-moz.jpg))

Answer (score 3):

Look around - do you ever see other people doing stuff like this?   How's your riding - are you strong enough to ride a up-to-100 kilo bike up the worst grade to your home ?   Is your bike up to the task - specifically brakes.

**Personally I'd try it**, but with a lighter load than pictured, and I'd use a couple more straps.   If this feels okay then step up to larger loads.   Avoid peak road times cos that's just aggravating others.  Also avoid hours of darkness, and consider using DRL lights on the load, or at least brightly coloured markers.

Those straps are trailer or motorcycle tiedowns.  You can use anything that is strong enough and tie them off to the trailer so the load cannot move.  Check your straps for tightness every few kilometres.

Weather comes into it as well.  Avoid towing into a headwind - its best to do this on a still day.   Also avoid rain/dampness because even if its not raining, the damp from the road will get on your stuff.  And braking co-efficient will not work in your favour if the road is wet.

As for trailer - finding a low one as pictured would be good.  The higher off the ground the more unstable on side winds and on corners.  My red ex-kids one is only rated to 30 kilos of live-load.  The hitch is important too, you don't want to loose the trailer at the wrong moment.

Also, approach stops much slower, lose speed earlier, and brake longer and more gently.  I've been jack knifed by my own loaded trailer at a red stoplight as the load lifted my rear wheel and shoved it sideways.

Take corners much slower than normal.  I managed to roll this 68 kg loaded trailer on a roundabout, which was embarrassing.  Max speed through a corner is 5-10 km/h.

[image]

To repeat - you need to have confidence in your bike and especially your brakes.  The trailer above easily doubled my stopping distance because of its mass, and also the risk of jack knifing meant I had to slow down the bike slower, over a longer window.

Comment: I am not very strong(software engineer with big belly). But I put my thrust on my Ebike.

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir counterweight is not a bad thing here.  Consider giving it a try if you can find a trailer to borrow.  Or jury rig something to see how it works for you.  All depends how handy you are with tools, and how much you want to spend on this.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this because it might be helpful for somebody else as well. 
My friends from work send me a link for renting trailers. I don't know why I searched all day yesterday and couldn't find something like [this danish renting trailer website.](https://freetrailer.dk/book-en-trailer/)